# NoSuchSessionException: A session is either terminated or not started error occurs when app is in background for more than 10 minutes in Appium

Tags: appium, appium-android

I have scenario to put the app in the background for more than 10 minutes but after ten minutes I am getting the following error

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: A session is either terminated or not started (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
```

If I run the app in background for 9 minutes it is working fine without any issues

**driver.runAppInBackground(Duration.ofMinutes(10));**

I have tried to fix this using **capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 3600);**

But it is also not working.

Refer [appium log](https://gist.github.com/alkaffkhanvrv/1e6d1bb58f33ac4b52ef2951536ad312)

Comment: Are you starting the Appium server internally (java) or are you launching the desktop version?  What framework are you using - Cucumber or JBehave?  The timeout issue might be with one of those.

Comment: I am using Appium desktop version. I am using Page Object model framework in Appium

Comment: I thought there might be a timeout setting in the desktop version of Appium, but I've not been able to locate it if one indeed exists.  I still suspect that something other than the capabilities setting is causing your timeout, I just don't know offhand what else it could be.  The reason I asked about framework is because that JBehave, for example, has a timeout for a story.  If you're just using JUnit or TestNG there probably is no corresponding timeout setting there that I know of.